# Disable view cache for pug (jade) templates in express

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I use `"express": "^4.14.0", "pug": "^2.0.0-beta6"`

```
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
...
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index.pug', {...});
}
```

When I use Express `render` function, it renders a template just once. If I change pug-template I'll get an old page version based on an already compiled template. For dev purposes, I need express recompiling .pug template for every `render` call. How can I achieve this?

I tried something like:

```
app.disable('view cache'); OR
app.set('view cache', false); OR
app.set('view cache', 'disabled');
```

But none of those were helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disappointing, but working:

```
const pug = require('pug');
const path = require('path');
res.send(pug.renderFile(path.join(__dirname,'template.pug'), templateObj));
```